# Angular UISelect issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

Im facing an issue with Angular UISelect and binding data to it using uiselect choices and repeat.

```
<ui-select class="form-control" ng-model="contractsHeader.AgencyName"   theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select an agency">{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="agency in agencies ">
                                    <div ng-bind-html="agency.Name"></div>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
```

Im seeing following issue in **chrome console**

TypeError: **undefined is not a function**
    at link (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.8.3/select.js:924:11)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6579:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:5986:15)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6573:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:5986:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:5891:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6005:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6600:18)
    at ngRepeatAction (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:20084:15)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12128:13)

**IE Console** i see this for each record im binding

TypeError: **Object expected**
   at link (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-select/0.8.3/select.js:924:11)
   at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6579:13)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:5986:15)
   at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6573:24)
   at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:5986:15)
   at publicLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:5891:30)
   at boundTranscludeFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6005:9)
   at controllersBoundTransclude (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:6600:11)
   at ngRepeatAction (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:20084:15)
   at $watchCollectionAction (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js:12128:13)

I can't see any dropdown value when i dropdown it, but i see rows are bound because when i select a value it shows up as selected.

the strange thing is when i use same piece of code in my sample application , it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Resolved : in my project i was using angular 1.2.16 after i upgraded to angular 1.2.18 version issue was fixed.